# Mapping strings in a nested data structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

Mapping two datastructures consisting of lists and dictionaries. The mapping from `data` should be recursively applied to the `payload` structure.

These are my inputs

```
data = {
    'a': 'Apple',
    'b': 'Ball',
    'c': 'Cat',
    'd': 'Dog',
    'e': 'Egg',
    'f': 'Fish',
    'g': 'Goat',
    'h': 'House',
    'i': 'Ice-Cream',
    'j': 'Jaguar',
    'k': 'Key',
    'l': 'Lock',
    'm': 'Map'
}
```

and

```
payload = {
    'PI': [
        {
            'one': 'a',
            'two': 'b',
            'three': 'c',
            'four': {
                'five': 'd',
                'six': 'e',
                'seven': 'f',
                'eight': 'g'
            }
        }, {
            'nine': 'h',
            'ten': 'i',
            'eleven': 'j',
            'twelve': 'k'
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
payload = {
    'PI': [
        {
            'one': 'Apple',
            'two': 'Ball',
            'three': 'Cat',
            'four': {
                'five': 'Dog',
                'six': 'Egg',
                'seven': 'Fish',
                'eight': 'Goat'
            }
        }, {
            'nine': 'House',
            'ten': 'Ice-Cream',
            'eleven': 'Jaguar',
            'twelve': 'Key'
        }
    ]
}
```

This my attempt at creating the mapping but it is not working

```
def mapping(payload):
    for k,v in payload.items():
        if(isinstance(v,dict)):
            mapping(v)
        elif(isinstance(v,list)):
            for item in v:
                mapping(item)
        else:
            try:
                v = data[v]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return payload
```

I get this instead:

```
{
    'PI': [
        {
            'four': {
                'eight': 'g', 
                'five': 'd', 
                'seven': 'f', 
                'six': 'e'
            },
            'one': 'a',
            'three': 'c',
            'two': 'b'
        },
        {
            'eleven': 'j',
            'nine': 'h',
            'ten': 'i',
            'twelve': 'k'
        }
    ]
}
```

Nothing has been replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use recursion; recurse for list values, and dictionary elements, and just map directly for everything else. Do not forget to *return* the result; the recursive function creates new dictionaries and lists:

```
def replace_strings(value, mapping):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return [replace_strings(v, mapping) for v in value]
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return {replace_strings(k, mapping): replace_strings(v, mapping)
                for k, v in value.items()}
    return mapping.get(value, value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> pprint(replace_strings(payload, data))
{'PI': [{'four': {'eight': 'Goat',
                  'five': 'Dog',
                  'seven': 'Fish',
                  'six': 'Egg'},
         'one': 'Apple',
         'three': 'Cat',
         'two': 'Ball'},
        {'eleven': 'Jaguar',
         'nine': 'House',
         'ten': 'Ice-Cream',
         'twelve': 'Key'}]}
```

Your code had several issues:

- You ignored the return value of any recursive call.
- You returned the original input, unaltered.